# What material is used to make luminescent placard on civil aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design, cockpit, airbus, security, cabin-design

I'm an engineer working in the civil aviation industry. Currently my company is preparing to make some placards. I've downloaded the drawings from Airbus. A drawing calls up the material of AD400 TV25/3881/83. I've seen the original OEM placard and I remember it's luminescent (it's located next to the emergency door).

I've searched "AD400" and "TV25/3881/83" as the keyword on Google but found nothing useful. I think it might be the spec of the material, but what it really is and where I can get it.

It will be greatly appreciated if someone can tell me more info on this material. It would be much better if someone can tell me where I can buy this material.

Update:
Below is how the placard looks like (a screenshot taken from the drawing):
[image]

The diamond 12 calls up the material of AD400 TV25/3881/83. Also the drawing says the base material is " MAKROFOL-E". I know "MAKROFOL" is a kind of PC film and it's a trademark of Bayer, but I didn't find this material on the website of Bayer either.
[image]

Comment: You appear to be asking what materials you should use to manufacture a piece of safety equipment. You absolutely must not rely on answers from random people on the internet for a safety critical system. Ask Airbus, not us.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly `AD400 TV25/3881/83` is, but if you are talking about a sign like this:

[image: Luminescent Sign]

It appears to be plastic and [Larchfield](http://www.larchfield-aerospace.com/placard-kits.html) sells them. This material `AD400 TV25/3881/83` could very well be a type of plastic, but I don't know about it.

In my opinion, you can contact companies which make or sell them (Larchfield or [this](http://www.nimbusaviation.com/#!luminescesent/c2537) or [this](http://www.aeroaid.com/interiors/decals-placards.php)) to get more reliable information.

Comment: Hi, Farhan. Thanks for your reply. I just edited my question and uploaded the drawing of that placard. Will this help you recall more info? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you've surmised, it's a type of polycarbonate.  It's also probably impregnated (or reverse-coated) with a phosphorescent compound so that it glows for a while after being exposed to light. (In the old days it would probably have been radioluminescent - phosphorescent compounds doped with radium or similar so they always glow, even when they haven't been exposed to light - but that's generally frowned upon these days.)

You could certainly order the material from Bayer if you need it in bulk (for making your own signs), or order [similar materials](https://www.inventables.com/technologies/glow-in-the-dark-and-clear-reverse-laserable-acrylic-sheet) which are probably cheaper. (Be aware that other materials may not meet flammability or environmental/safety requirements for aerospace applications though: In particular many of these sheets are PVC, which would produce some nasty byproducts in a post-crash fire!)

If you're looking at this for aerospace purposes (for example building a cabin simulator for flight crew training) I'd do as Farhan suggested and contact one of the companies that produces replacement placards and just buy them - it's the ultimate level of realism, and way easier than making them yourself. If you're looking to make placards for your own aircraft out of similar material they might also be able to source it for you (or be willing to do a custom placard run, for a price).